# ¿Hacer agrupaciones de datos en diferentes columnas en SQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, plsql

Tengo una tabla en la que hay información que recojo dependiendo del estado, necesito que se muestre una tabla que recoja la cuenta de las councidencias de cada uno de los resultados. Es decir si tengo los siguientes datos:

- 10 resultados en estado OK
- 3 resultados en estado NOK
- 0 resultados en estado SOK
- 0 resultados en estado FOK

Me tendría que aparecer una tabla de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema es que me devuelve una tabla de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, se repiten los resultados por cada valor que hay en la tabla.

La consulta que estoy usando (y que seguro que no está bien planteada) es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(RESULTADO) FROM DATOS WHERE RESULTADO = 'OK') OK,
    (SELECT COUNT(RESULTADO) FROM DATOS WHERE RESULTADO = 'SOK') SOK,
    (SELECT COUNT(RESULTADO) FROM DATOS WHERE RESULTADO = 'FOK') FOK,
    (SELECT COUNT(RESULTADO) FROM DATOS WHERE RESULTADO = 'NOK') NOK    
FROM  DATOS
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un case condicionado por cada uno de los count, y realizar una lectura a la tabla.

Creo la tabla con datos.

```
Create table Datos (id int, Resultado varchar(3))
```

La pueblo de información.

```
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (1,'OK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (2,'OK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (3,'SOK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (4,'OK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (5,'SOK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (6,'OK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (7,'FOK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (8,'FOK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (9,'NOK');
Insert into Datos (id, Resultado) Values (10,'OK');
```

Y ahora consulto los mismos.

```
SELECT COUNT(Case when RESULTADO = 'OK'  THEN 1 END) AS  OK,
       COUNT(Case when RESULTADO = 'SOK' THEN 1 END) AS SOK,
       COUNT(Case when RESULTADO = 'FOK' THEN 1 END) AS FOK,
       COUNT(Case when RESULTADO = 'NOK' THEN 1 END) AS NOK

 FROM DATOS;
```

Al realizar un case condicional, sin incluir más columnas, no te es necesario incluir group by.

[image: Resultados]

Comment: No me está funcionando, me sigue saliendo la misma cantidad de repeticiones.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que en la tabla o query no estas utilizando más columnas?

Comment: Seguro, solo está lo que se muestra en las imágenes. He probado la edición que has hecho y me sale ya correctamente, no recuerdo si lo que propusiste ayer era diferente o no a lo de ahora, igual en el caso de ser igual me dejé algo, la cosa es que ahora realmente me saca las columnas como debería. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda y tiempo!